# Conditional Expectation with elliptical random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

In a paper I am reading it is written the following:

> Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n) \sim E_n(\mu, \Sigma, \phi)$ be a
>   elliptical-distributed random vector; let $S = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$.
>   Then $$E[X_k \mid S=s] = \mu_k + \frac{\sigma_{k,S}}{\sigma_{S}^2}(s -
>  \mu_S)$$
>   where $\mu_k$ is the mean of $X_k$, $\mu_S, \sigma^2_S$ are the mean and variance of $S$, and $\sigma_{k,S}$ is the covariance between $X_k$ and $S$

I have tried to prove this but without luck. Can anybody help?

**Thoughts**

I tried the following:

$$E[X_k \mid S=s] = \int xf_{X_k \mid S = s}(x) dx$$

Since $$f_{X_k \mid S = s}(x)  = \frac{f_{(X_k, S)}(x,s)}{f_S(s)}$$

I get

$$E[X_k \mid S=s] = \frac 1{f_S(s)} \int x f_{(X_k, S)}(x,s) dx$$

I know the distribution of the vector $(X_k, S)$ (Since it is a linear transformation of the vector $X$, it is still elliptical distributed and I can compute it's mean and variance; the elliptical generator $\phi$  is still the same).

But how to simplify it further to get to the result stated in the paper?

Comment: I do not have the time to provide a nice self-contained answer. But I think your observation that $(X_k,S)$ is elliptical together with the formula for conditioning on partitions of joint elliptical distributions found in Theorem 2.18 of "Symmetric multivariate and related distributions" by Fang, Ng and Kotz (https://www.worldcat.org/title/symmetric-multivariate-and-related-distributions/oclc/123206055) should do the job.

Comment: @gg Thank you! That theorem indeed works! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a special case of a more general result for conditional distribution of elliptical random variables; see theorem 2.18 of the book "Symmetric multivariate and related distributions" by Fang, Ng and Kotz for the statement and proof. Thanks to @gg in the comments for the resource!